# Problems with FULL HD resolution on Android

Tags: android, resolution

I have a problem with resolution on my Nexus5. I'm programming an application that should work on all the resolutions on all the phones. On my Galaxy Note 8 everything is ok, also on all other devices that don't have HD resolution. The problem only occurred on Nexus5 and new Nexus7 (both with full HD).

Any idea on how to fix the problem?

Here's a print screen of what it should look like:

> [image]

And here's the one from Nexus5:

> [image]

Here's the XML layout code:

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:weightSum="1">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_weight=".15">

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/body"
    android:layout_weight="0.70">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:id="@+id/rows"
        android:weightSum="7">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="UP"
            android:id="@+id/UPbutton"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:id="@+id/columns"
            android:weightSum="7">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="LEFT"
                android:id="@+id/LEFTbutton3"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/column1">


                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewROW1"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/osnovna"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp" />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewROW2"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/osnovna"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp" />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewROW3"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/osnovna"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp" />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewROW4"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/osnovna"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp" />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewROW5"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/osnovna"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/column2">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewROW1"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/osnovna"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp" />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewROW2"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/osnovna"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp" />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewROW3"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/osnovna"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp" />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewROW4"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/osnovna"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp" />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewROW5"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/osnovna"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/column3">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewROW1"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/osnovna"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp" />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewROW2"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/osnovna"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp" />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewROW3"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/osnovna"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp" />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewROW4"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/osnovna"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp" />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewROW5"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/osnovna"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/column4">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewROW1"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/osnovna"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp" />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewROW2"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/osnovna"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp" />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewROW3"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/osnovna"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp" />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewROW4"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/osnovna"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp" />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewROW5"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/osnovna"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/column5">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewROW1"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/osnovna"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp" />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewROW2"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/osnovna"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp" />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewROW3"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/osnovna"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp" />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewROW4"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/osnovna"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp" />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewROW5"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/osnovna"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="RIGHT"
                android:id="@+id/RIGHTbutton4"
                android:layout_weight="1.5" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="DOWN"
            android:id="@+id/DOWNbutton2"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_weight="0.15"></RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You need to provide more details. At least your layout xml files.

Comment: Use Hierarchy View to determine where you are going wrong, since we will have no idea without any code.

Comment: Just attached XML. Any idea?